# Cython: invalid operand types

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a C++ class implementation which I want to expose to Python with Cython.
The class interface is something like this (each operator's implementation involves some private attributes so they cannot be inline implementations):

```
class Quantity {

private:
// Some implementation -- 

public:

    explicit Quantity(...);
    Quantity(const Quantity &);
    ~Quantity(){};
    double operator()(const std::string) const;

    friend Quantity operator+ (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation };
    friend Quantity operator- (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend Quantity operator* (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend Quantity operator/ (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend bool operator < (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend bool operator <= (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend bool operator > (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend bool operator >= (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend bool operator == (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};
    friend bool operator != (const Quantity & a, const Quantity & b) {//implementation};

};
```

.pxd (partial):

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "quantity.h" namespace "munits":

    cdef cppclass Quantity:
        Quantity(...)

        bool operator< (const Quantity &)
        double operator()(string)

        Quantity operator+(const Quantity &)
```

.pyx (partial) :

```
cdef class PyQuantity:

    cdef :
        Quantity *_thisptr

    def __cinit__(PyQuantity self, ... ):
        self._thisptr = new Quantity(...)

    def __cinit__(PyQuantity self, Quantity ot):
        self._thisptr = new Quantity(ot)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._thisptr != NULL:
            del self._thisptr

    cdef int _check_alive(self) except -1:
        if self._thisptr == NULL:
            raise RuntimeError("Wrapped C++ object is deleted")
        else:
            return 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self._check_alive()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_tp, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self._thisptr != NULL:
            del self._thisptr
            self._thisptr = NULL # inform __dealloc__
        return False # propagate exceptions

    def __richcmp__(PyQuantity self, PyQuantity other, op):
        if op == 0:
            return self._thisptr[0] < other._thisptr[0]


    def __add__(PyQuantity self, PyQuantity other):

        return new PyQuantity(self._thisptr[0] + other._thisptr[0])
```

The implementation for the operator() and all the comparison operators work but for other math operators like '+' I can't get it right. I also checked variations described here: [Cython: Invalid operand types for '+' (btVector3; btVector3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383792/cython-invalid-operand-types-for-btvector3-btvector3)
But I'm still getting either Invalid operand types or Cannot convert 'Quantity' to Python object. What am I missing, why do other operators work and addition and such not?

Comment: In the link you provide, the answer use no references in the .pxd (`Quantity operator+(Quantity)`), did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `__cinit__` is not allowed as far as I remember

```
def __cinit__(PyQuantity self, ... ):
    self._thisptr = new Quantity(...)

def __cinit__(PyQuantity self, Quantity ot):
    self._thisptr = new Quantity(ot)
```

Arguments to `__cinit__` should be python objects (object, list, tuple, int, bint, double, PyQuantity, ...) and not a C++ class Quantity.

```
def __cinit__(PyQuantity self, PyQuantity other=None):
    if other is not None:
        self._thisptr = new Quantity(other._thisptr[0])
    else:
        self._thisptr = new Quantity()
```

This

```
def __add__(PyQuantity self, PyQuantity other):
    return new PyQuantity(self._thisptr[0] + other._thisptr[0])
```

could probably be written as

```
def __add__(PyQuantity self, PyQuantity other):
    cdef PyQuantity nobj = PyQuantity(self)
    nobj._thisptr[0] += other._thisptr[0]

    return nobj
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of the accepted answer actually works.
The problem with that was += is not implemented (for a reason) so 
    `nobj._thisptr[0] = self._thisptr[0] + other._thisptr[0]` was used, but this causes segmentation errors - obviously, since the resulting Quantity object is not heap alolocated.
 The final implementation is:

```
    def __add__(PyQuantity self, PyQuantity other):
        cdef PyQuantity nobj = PyQuantity()
        nobj._thisptr = new Quantity(self._thisptr[0] +  other._thisptr[0])
        return nobj
```